Missing entities in msh file
I have a problem understanding the .msh file provided by Gmesh.
Here is the example I am using:
Point(1) = {0, -0, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(2) = {1, 0, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(3) = {1, 1, 0, 1.0};
//+
Point(4) = {0., 1, 0, 1.0};
//+
Line(1) = {1, 2};
//+
Line(2) = {2, 3};
//+
Line(3) = {3, 4};
//+
Line(4) = {4, 1};
//+
Curve Loop(1) = {4, 1, 2, 3};
//+
Plane Surface(1) = {1};

This gives this mesh:

I am counting 5 nodes, 8 edges and 4 elements.
The msh file (version 2) I got:
$MeshFormat
2.2 0 8
$EndMeshFormat
$Nodes
5
1 0 -0 0
2 1 0 0
3 1 1 0
4 0 1 0
5 0.5 0.5 0
$EndNodes
$Elements
12
1 15 2 0 1 1
2 15 2 0 2 2
3 15 2 0 3 3
4 15 2 0 4 4
5 1 2 0 1 1 2
6 1 2 0 2 2 3
7 1 2 0 3 3 4
8 1 2 0 4 4 1
9 2 2 0 1 1 2 5
10 2 2 0 1 4 1 5
11 2 2 0 1 2 3 5
12 2 2 0 1 3 4 5
$EndElements

I can see the 5 nodes.
However, in the elements, it only mentions the 4 vertices of the square and the 4 edges of the square. I don't see the fifth node nor the edges related to it.
Did I do something wrong or is it normal ?

In the $Elements section the mesh itself is described by 9-12 lines. There are triangles (1,2,5), (4,1,5), (2,3,5) and (3,4,5). One could see, that the node 5 is present in the all four mesh elements. Lines 1-4 describe geometry (not mesh) vertices and lines (5-8) describe geometry (not mesh) edges.
